# Angular JS - angular-ui-load - error undefined

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, angular-ui, angular-ui-router-extras

I'would like to use the "angular-ui-load" in my app angular.
The problem, my script js is undefined
Error in dev consol firefox :

```
"Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'DetailsCtrl' is not a function, got undefined
```

Now, The angular-ui-load declared in index.html

```html
        <!-- build:js scripts/modules.js -->
        <script src="bower_components/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-cookies/angular-cookies.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
        <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->

        <!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/scripts.js -->
        <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/services/ui-load.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/alert.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/controllers/users.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/directives/ui-jq.js"></script>
        <!-- endbuild -->
```

and 'ui.load' my app.js is :

```js
'use strict';

  angular.module('webApp', [
  'ngCookies',
  'ngResource',
  'ngSanitize',
  'ui.router',
  'ui.load',
  'ui.jq',
  'zumba.angular-waypoints'
])
  .run(
    [          '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams',
      function ($rootScope,   $state,   $stateParams) {
          $rootScope.$state = $state;
          $rootScope.$stateParams = $stateParams;        
      }
    ]
  )

  .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    //delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
    $stateProvider
      .state('users', {
        url: '/users',
        templateUrl: 'views/users.html',
        controller:'UserCtrl'
      })
      .state('users.details', {
        url: '/details/:id_user',
        templateUrl: 'views/details.html',
        //controller:'UserCtrl'
        resolve: {
                  deps: ['uiLoad',
                     function( uiLoad){
                       return uiLoad.load('scripts/controllers/details.js');
                      }]
                  }
      })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated :-) ?

Comment: what is 'DetailsCtrl' in your app, i guess controller is missing in 'users.details' .

Comment: 'DetailsCtrl' after declared controler angular, now i will need uiLoad. Yes, the controler is missing in 'users.details' because the ngular-ui-load dosn't running or bad install :-/